# Modifying a List in a function in place

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

An example will be most specific:

```
func[list_, column_] := list[[All, column]] = Map[#*2 &, list[[All, column]]];
```

This throws errors.

I want to avoid doing something like this:

```
func2[list_] := Map[#*2 &; list];
list[[All, 2]] = func2[list[[All,2]]]
```

because nesting a couple of functions raises complexity unnecessarily, the output would have to be reassigned every time.

Thanks in advance.

As a followup, using HoldFirst works fine, but using the so defined function in a Map gives again errors.

The setup is as follows:

create a nested list

```
testList = Table[Table[{x y, x y 2}, {x, 1,3}], {y,1,3}]
```

define afunc with HoldFirst Attribute

```
afunc = Function[{list, col}, list[[All, col]] = Map[# * 2 &, list[[All, col]]], HoldFirst]
```

and another function using the first

```
bfunc[nestedList_, col_] := Map[afunc[#, col] &, nestedList]
```

now, a call to

```
bfunc[testList, 2]
```

should alter the 2'nd columns of the nested lists I'd expect, but it instead throws errors

i've tried to set Attribute HoldFirst on this function as well but it didn't work out as expected

Comment: Well, with your follow-up, you really opened a can of worms. Without a very detailed discussion, here is a working version of your `bfunc`: `ClearAll[bfunc];
SetAttributes[bfunc, HoldFirst]; bfunc[nestedList_, col_] :=  Table[With[{i = i}, afunc[nestedList[[i]], col]], {i, 
Length[nestedList]}]`. Note that 1: You should have used patterns and `HoldFirst` for `bfunc` 2:the construction `f[#]&` is *not the same* as `f`,since it leaks evaluation during the parameter-passing in a pure function 3. `Map` is a wrong tool for the task, since there is no way with it to prevent evaluation of sub-parts.

Comment: I want to add that generally, programming with the pass-by-reference style is a bit going against the idiomatic Mathematica, and so you should get a really good understanding of evaluation process if you don't want nasty surprises on every mile of this road.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm having a quite strong background in OOP and procedural programming languages, the functional approach is making me troubles though, but I think I'm not alone.

Comment: Note also that Mathematica is not really a functional language at its core - it emulates functional paradigm (quite well), but its core is term-rewriting. Many of the issues here are specific to Mathematica, for example quite complex evaluation control, or patterns. If you are interested in FP in Mathematica specifically, you may check out [my book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/), which is heavily centered around an FP paradigm. It does not however explain evaluation in great detail.

Comment: @Leonid, what do you mean by "... there is no way with it to prevent evaluation of sub-parts"?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I mean that if you have a list stored in some variable (say, `lst`), and you have a function which sets some expression to something (like `Set`), I don't see any way that you can use `Map` and this function to separately reset parts of `lst` to new values. This is why I was using `Table` with index injection. And the only reason *that* worked is that `Part` is a lower-level function, and in particularly you can assign sub-parts directly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You basically need a pass-by-reference semantics, which in Mathematica can be emulated with `Hold`-attributes. Add a `HoldFirst` attribute to your function:

```
SetAttributes[func,HoldFirst]
```

and you should be fine. Without it, `list` evaluates to its value before the assignment is attempted, and since expressions in Mathematica are immutable, you get an error.

To address your question in comments, the one-liner you asked for can be this:

```
func = Function[{list,column}, 
         list[[All, column]] = Map[#*2 &, list[[All, column]]],
         HoldFirst
       ]
```

Note however that, since this is a pure function, you can not do argument checks as elegantly as you can with patterns, and you can not overload your functions on different arguments as elegantly.

Note also that, while yet another way to do this is to keep your function as it is but rather wrap the first argument in `Unevaluated` in every function call, I would strongly advise against that. The reason is that it makes the function itself not self-contained, because it has to *assume* that the user will always remember to use `Unevaluated` (which it shouldn't), and there is no way to test whether or not the user actually did use it.

Comment: is there a one liner to do that in the function definition directly?

Comment: @phil Yes, see my edit.

Comment: Hey, I´m counting four lines ;-)

Comment: @Yves That only depends on the magnification of the Mathematica notebook :)

Comment: Philosophically I'm curious as to the motivation for doing this. It seems to re-introduce state. If the list needs to evolve, couldn't that be achieved with Nest or Fold ?

Comment: @image_doctor I agree in general, but this may be very useful sometimes for efficiency reasons. For a relatively non-trivial example, have a look at [my implementation of quicksort](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/69d53a2ffa5a640e) using pass-by-reference - it is more efficient than the one based on more standard Mathematica techniques.