# Passing large list by reference

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, performance-tuning

I have the following problem: I would like to control evaluation of a variable that points to a list. For example, frequently in the code I have functions of the form that are supposed to work on large lists (modifying them frequently):

```
updateList[list_, newvalue_, index_]:= (list[[index]] = newvalue)
```

to be used (many times) as

```
list = {1, 2, 3};
While[...
updateList[list, -2, 2];
]
```

and I should get immediately

```
list = {1, -2, 3}
```

The problem is that the list gets evaluated immediately if one is not careful and the assignment statement fails. I have tried to solve this by defining

```
Attributes[updateList] = {HoldAll}
```

It works, but I realized that this can get very complicated since I am passing the list quite a bit around in a rather big package. Some function have Hold, some not, on some I would actually like to have the second and the third argument Holding while others not... To tell you the truth, I do not feel I have the control of this behavior; sometimes it evaluates and sometimes it does not, and it is driving me crazy.

The reason why I am doing this is to save memory. One could, of course, use the following definition

```
updateList[list_, newValue_, index_] := (newList = list; newList[[index]] = newvalue)
```

and use it like

```
list = updateList[list, -2, 2]
```

to the same effect, but this will consume quite a bit of memory (my list are huge). So I am trying to control memory usage by updating storage. I guess I am trying to use them as pointers.

A more serious example would be

```
updateList[list_, args__] := 
   Block[{indicies, newvalues}, 
      indicies = figureOutIndiciesToChange[args];
      newvalues = figureOutValuesToChange[args];
      list[[indicies]] = newvalues
   ];
```

or even a more nasty example (actually happens):

```
updateList[list_, args__] := 
   Block[{indicies, newvalues}, 
      indicies = figureOutIndiciesToChange[args];
      nestedCallToUpdateTheList[...., list, ...];
      newvalues = figureOutValuesToChange[args];
      list[[indicies]] = newvalues
   ];
```

where

```
(* here list can be third argument, or even last *)     
nestedCallToUpdateTheList[...., list_, ...] :=          
   While[a big loop,
      list[[dynamicIndicies] = dynamicValues]];
   ]
```

So I have a principle (open) question: how to update long lists (parts of it) in the most efficient way if such lists are passed through several layers of functional calls? Is there a way to achieve this without using HoldAll? Perhaps using more direct Hold functionality? Anyway, I would like to learn how to be in control...

EDIT1: Based on the comments below, I would like to add another requirement; Assume that all this has to be done within the function. Is this possible at all? A bullet-proof way would be

```
updateLilst[___] := fail["please used Hold on the list argument"];
updateList[...,list_Hold,...] := do the work on the list;
```

Or...?

EDIT2: By the way, how to test whether an argument is evaluated in the function?

p.s. I tried with Hold, but it is tricky since it is not make the assignment with a Held variable...

Comment: What's the reason for using a function in the first place instead of running `list[[2]]=-2` directly to modify the list? *tutorial/AddingRemovingAndModifyingListElements*

Comment: it has to be done programatically due to the nature of the problem. I am solving numerically equations of motion for a dynamical system. at every time step these lists have to get incrementally updated. there is no problem when one clones the list while updating it. the key issue is how to do it without cloning the list.

Comment: The FullForm of the previous is: `Set[Part[list, 2], -2]` if you prefer that notation. And neither clones the list, after: `list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
list[[2 ;; 3]] = -1;` list will be modified so `list=={1,-1,-1,4,5}`

Comment: I know. The problem is that when you start passing it around in many funcitons it can get tricky. For example, updateList function will break down if its attributes are not defined to HoldAll on the list.

Comment: That last example helped me understand!

Comment: +1 I think this is a great question. I have to pass large arrays by reference as well, otherwise my memory consumption goes through the roof.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just use `HoldAll` on all the functions?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3616/modifying-a-list-in-a-function-in-place

Comment: You may find [this paper by Robby Villegas](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/villegas/UnevaluatedExpressions/index.html) and interesting read.

Comment: Also this might be interesting: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/how-to-pass-a-symbolname-to-a-function-with-any-of-the-hold-attributes/2677#2677

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
makeList[symb_, l_] := Module[{x},
  symb /: list[symb] := x;
  symb /: updateList[symb, spec_, val_] := (x[[spec]] = val);
  symb /: listParts[symb, spec_] := (x[[spec]])
  x = l;
  symb
]
```

After doing

```
makeList[foo,{1,2,3}]
```

the list is stored in a "local" variable `x$42` (the specific number is chosen by mathematica). You can pass around the symbol `foo` without having to worry about `x$42` being accidentally evaluated. You can access and update the list via `list`, `updateList` and `listParts`.

Along those lines, you could also do the following (disclaimer: redefining `Set` and `Part` is probably a bad idea):

```
caveatEmptor[symb_] := Module[{x},
  Unprotect[Set];
  Unprotect[Part];
  Set[symb, val_] := Set[x, val];
  Set[Part[symb, spec__], val_] := Set[Part[x, spec], val];
  Part /: Part[symb, spec__] := Part[x, spec];
  show[symb] := x;
  Protect[Set];
  Protect[Part];
]
```

After running

```
caveatEmptor[foo]
```

the following appear to behave as normal:

```
foo={1,2,3}
foo[[2]]=4
foo[[2;;3]]
```

but `foo` is still an undefined symbol so you can pass it without worry of evaluation. You have to do

```
show[foo]
```

to see the value you set.

Comment: I put in the `TagSetDelayed` (/:) so that you could get rid of the definitions by doing `Remove[foo]`. I'm not sure how this will affect performance.

Comment: This is indeed very close what I would like to achieve. In principle, if I understand correctly, you have defined an object called list. Smart! I wish it was my idea... Have to think though how would it apply to my problem, but looks very, very close. Many thanks!

Comment: I agree that modifying Set/Part is not such a good idea. Though one might try to create own versions of these commands. This would make the code much more readable actually. Thanks!

Comment: Could you not set UpValues to Set and Part instead of Unprotect then? +1

Comment: @Murta: If I use TagSetDelayed on the fifth line, `symb` appears too deep for an assigned rule to be found. The upvalue in the sixth line is needed; mathematica does not like to do `x[[3]]:=y[[3]]`.

Comment: Now I get. I'm new in UpValues. Tks!

Answer (score 6):

You can set the attribute `HoldFirst` to only hold the first argument. And define the function such that it only accepts a symbol since you can't do things like:

```
{1,2,3}[[1]]=9
```

The code:

```
Clear[updateList];
Attributes[updateList] = {HoldFirst};
updateList[list_Symbol, value_, index_] := (list[[index]] = value;)

i = 1; val = 2;
list = {0, 0, 0};
updateList[list, val, i]
list
(* {2,0,0} *)
```

If you try to supply a list directly:

```
updateList[{1, 2, 3}, 2, 1]
```

It will remain unevaluated as `updateList[{1, 2, 3}, 2, 1]`, but imo it'd be better to throw an error.

In the end you are left with something that's just a limited version of `list[[i]]=val`

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me out. Indeed, I am aware of the HoldFirst command. The problem is that it gets very tricky when there are many nested functinal calls and the list variable ends up being third or fourth argument way down... Also, there might be optional arguments etc. I would just like to learn how to exercise a firm controll of the beast :) Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 5):

Only to answer a specific point, because it is too large to fit in the comments.

You say

> on some I would actually like to have the second and the third argument Holding while others not

You can pass specific arguments by what is called "by reference" in other languages, while passing the others by value. So you do not have to make the whole function `HoldAll`. This is done by requiring the caller to wrap the argument itself with `Unevaluated`. This makes the wrapped argument pass by reference while others pass by value (the default).

```
foo[a_, b_, c_] := Module[{tmpA = a, tmpC = c},
  tmpA[[2]] = 5; 
  b[[2]] = 5; 
  tmpC[[2]] = 5;
  {tmpA, b, tmpC}
  ]
a = Table[1, {10}]; b = a; c = a;
{a, b, c} = foo[a, Unevaluated[b], c]
```

Btw, This is actually not a good way to do things, and I do not use this method any more, but did use once or twice before.

This can make things confusing when looking at the function itself, as there is no indication inside the function that some input(s) should be passed by reference and some by value. It also can have some other bad side-effects and might not be too robust for all uses. So I am not suggesting this method, just saying it is there to look at.

Comment: this was very good idea. perhaps one could try to define foo[a_, b_Unevaluated, c_] := ... with foo[___] := fail to ensure that the caller is doing its part of the bargin?

Comment: @zorank The `Unevaluated` wrapper will be eated on evaluation of the enclosing function. But you can check that the symbol is unevaluated by `foo[a_, b_Symbol, c_]`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution a la Tobias Hagge:

```
makeList[___] := invalidInvocation;
makeList[symb_Symbol,list_]:=
   Block[{pointer, initialized, spec, val, temp},
      initialized = listInitialized[symb]===True;
      If[initialized, 
         Print["removeList before re-initializing it"];
         Abort[]
      ];
      pointer=Unique["listStorage$"];
      temp = 
      {
         Hold[pointer=Evaluate@list],
         Hold[symb/:listExtractElements[symb]:=pointer],
         Hold[symb/:listUpdateElements[symb,spec_,val_]:=(pointer[[spec]]=val)],
         Hold[symb/:listExtractParts[symb,spec_]:=(pointer[[spec]])],
         Hold[symb /:removeList[symb] := (Remove[pointer]; Unprotect[symb];Remove[symb])]
      };
      Map[ReleaseHold[# /. OwnValues[pointer]]&, temp];
      symb/:listInitialized[symb]:=True;
      Protect[symb];
      Null
  ];
```

Note: I use Block since the function will be called many times.

We create a list

```
In[3]:= makeList[list, {1,2,3}]
In[4]:= Definition[list]
Out[4]= Attributes[list]={Protected}
listExtractElements[list]^:=listStorage$3
    listInitialized[list]^:=True
    removeList[list]^:=(Remove[listStorage$3];Unprotect[list];Remove[list])
listUpdateElements[list,spec_,val_]^:=listStorage$3[[spec]]=val
    listExtractParts[list,spec_]^:=listStorage$3[[spec]]
```

If we try to make it again it will complain.

```
In[5]:= makeList[list, {1,2,3}]
...removeList before re-initializing it
Out[5]= $Aborted
```

If we try to assign a value to it it will complain

```
In[6]:= list = 1
During evaluation of In[6]:= Set::wrsym: Symbol list is Protected. >>
Out[6]= 1
```

we can only operate on it by the methods we have defined

```
In[7]:= listUpdateElements[list, 2, newElement]
Out[7]= newElement
In[8]:= listExtractElements[list]
Out[8]= {1,newElement,3}
```

Only if we remove it explicitly

```
In[9]:= removeList[list]
```

we can assign values to it

```
In[10]:= list = 1
Out[10]= 1
```

If we try to make a list on already assigned symbol it will complain

```
In[11]:= makeList[list, {2, 3, 5}]
Out[11]= invalidInvocation
```

The symbol has to be clean, then assignemnt can be done

```
In[12]:= Clear[list]
In[13]:= makeList[list, {2, 3, 5}]
In[14]:= listExtractElements[list]
Out[14]= {2,3,5}
```

Many thanks Tobias! This was a brilliant suggestion. A foolproof concept with absolute controll of what is going on.

Zoran