# Replace all elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have a set that looks like:

```
s = {{1, 2, 3} -> 9, {4, 1, 9} -> 9, {3, 7, 3} -> 1};
```

Now, I want to replace each element of the set by the lhs of "`->`". The result should look like this:

```
s = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 1, 9}, {3, 7, 3}};
```

### The problem:

I only want to **modify** the list `s` **without creating a new list**. This is why `Replace[]` and `Map[]` cannot be used in this scenario.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `list[[All, 1]]`

Comment: btw. `Map[First, {{1, 2, 3} -> 9, {4, 1, 9} -> 9, {3, 7, 3} -> 1}]` does the job, but i want to REPLACE the elements. Thank you!

Comment: `Replace[{{1, 2, 3} -> 9, {4, 1, 9} -> 9, {3, 7, 3} -> 1}, x_ :>   First[x], {1}]` ?

Comment: Your question is not clear: Oska's answer and your Map and andres answer all accomplish the task as you've asked it. If this isn't what you want, you need to be more explicit.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE.  I agree with bill's concern; I have closed this post to answers to head off people answering the wrong question.  Please clarify what *you are actually trying to do*.  I will then reopen it.

Comment: I changed the initial post. I hope it's clear now. (?)

Comment: `s=[[All,1]]` will do what you want. On version 9.01 it worked. here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Fy2.png)

Comment: @Nasser, the output is the return value of `s[[All, 1]]`. s has not changed at all. Also I don't understand your code: `s=[[All,1]]`.

Comment: Does my answer address your concern, or is it for a reason besides memory consumption that you want to modify in place?

Answer (score 2):

You state that you want to modify the original rule list rather than creating a new list.  I assume that you want to avoid copying the list for memory reasons.  I think you are unlikely to do better than the simple `list = list[[All, 1]]` recommended by [Öskå](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1356/oska).  We can see that the additional memory used is fairly small, at least with the type of sample rules you gave:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;

big = MapThread[Rule, {RandomInteger[9, {5*^6, 3}], RandomInteger[99, 5*^6]}];

MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> 1614925768
> ```

After the operation:

```
big = big[[All, 1]];
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> 1700726928
> ```

Using `First` by comparison (in a separate kernel):

```
big = First /@ big;
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> 1940364440
> ```

`Part` only uses an additional ~5.3% RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, discussed several times, e.g. in [passing large list by reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19445/passing-large-list-by-reference), is to use the "trick" of holding the argument of a function to pass it by reference.

```
ClearAll[f];
Attributes[f] = {HoldFirst};
f[li_] := Do[li[[i]] = First[li[[i]]], {i, Length[li]}];

f[s]
```

produces the desired outcome of modifying the list in place as you desired, without copying it.